# oauth2 : Is it recommanded to cache the public key used to validate the JWT token on every request?

Tags: oauth-2.0

Is it a common/useful practice to keep a copy of the public key used to validate each jwt token on every request to avoid fetching it every time from the authorization server ?

Is it an available option when using Spring Security ? or is there an implicit cache of the public key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common practice and useful to keep a copy of JWKs that have been pulled from a JWKs URI and use the cached copy for performance reasons.

In fact the JWK spec has been setup in such a way that it recommends this practice by virtue of adding a `kid` (or: Key Identifier) claim to the JWK and the tokens.

Whenever a signing key is updated/rolled-over, the Sender would update the `kid` in the JWKs and the signed tokens so that the Receiver would notice that the new `kid` is not available in the cache yet, thus pull the updated JWKs again from the JWKs URI.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this detailed answer. Would you know if Spring security applies this strategy by default ? It looks like the only parameter is "jwk-set-uri"

Comment: Oh ok, I've found the answer, there is actually a default cache with a 5 min duration : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60409678/how-to-increase-remotejwkset-cache-ttl-in-spring-security-5-2